# Serializing Object to XML without [xmlns=""]

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, xml-namespaces

The Manual of Jackson XML write Object like this

```
<Simple>
  <x>1</x>
  <y>2</y>
</Simple>
```

in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml
but in my code,it has [xmlns="" ],and it can't be in my business.

My code:

```
public class Sample {
    private int id=1;
    private String name="abc";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Sample()));
       //<Sample xmlns=""><id>1</id><name>abc</name></Sample>
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/32

Answer (score 1):

As described in the last posting to [issue 32](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/32):

> Using Stax implementation other than one that is bundled with JDK:
>   both Woodstox and Aalto work in a way that does not produce this extra
>   (harmless) namespace declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding woodstox dependency already resolve your question.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
  <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And you can use default (de)serialization

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
```